# #1442 - Can't update table 'contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting this error in MySQL:

> #1442 - Can't update table 'contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

this is what I have

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Company` (
  `Id` int(50) NOT NULL ,
  `CompanyName` varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
  `ExternalId` varchar(20) NOT NULL
  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Contact` (
  `ContactId` int (50) NOT NULL ,
  `CompanyId` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `CompanyExtId` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `Company`
ADD Primary key (`Id`);

ALTER TABLE `Company`
MODIFY `Id` int (50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


ALTER TABLE `Contact`
ADD Primary key (`ContactId`);

ALTER TABLE `Contact`
MODIFY `ContactId` int (50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


ALTER TABLE `Contact`
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_contact
  FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`)
  REFERENCES `Company`(`Id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;


CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_Contact 
AFTER INSERT ON Contact 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE `Contact` SET CompanyExtId = Company.ExternalId WHERE company.id=contact.CompanyId;
END
```

Comment: You define the relationship between contacts and companies through companyid field. Not sure why you need CompanyExtId field in both tables. If you have this field in one of the tables, you do not need a trigger to keep them in sync.

Comment: As the error says this is not allowed in mysql, you can set NEW. values in a before trigger BUT you would have to select from company -which you said in the same question yesterday that you cannot do -

Comment: You were also asked yesterday what you are trying to achieve - you haven't responded.

Comment: Typically, I would just use the following query to get what I'm looking for:

SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Company.ExternalId from Contact join Company ON Contact.CompanyId = Company.Id where Contact.id = <something>;

Unfortunately, the utility I need to use to query the database requires all the data to be in the same table, so I'm relegated to replicating the Company.ExternalId to the Contact record so I can use the following ridiculous query:

SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, CompanyExtId from TBLcontact where Id = <something>;

Comment: @KirinyetBrian consider using a view and point that tool to the view rather than a table.